Setup for Wordpress with Raspbery and Github
Hello wonderful people of the internet,
Noob question here...
I plan the following usecase: I want to create a website which I want to host only locally on a raspberry. For development of the website I use my PC setup with wordpress local. The changes I make on the website I want to commit to a repository and pull the result on the raspberry (as the raspberry will run on a remote location I plan to always pull the latest version to the raspberry automatically in the future).
I already managed the following:

create a repository in Github
create a website in local

What I really dont find is how to commit the whole website to my repository and how to continue on my raspberry. I searched for it several hours now. Perhaps I dont search for the right tags...
So any help or link to a tutorial would be highly appreciated! If you need additional information please let me know
Thank you very much!

the problem is too large and needs breaking down, e.g. how to commit an entire site to a git repo on its own is multiple questions, and separate from how to host a web server on a Raspberry Pi ( I'm assuming you meant a Pi and not one of the other Single board computers? ) There are also questions specific to Local as well ( assuming you meant Local by WP Engine and not a different local environment setup ). Narrow down your question to one of these or it may be too broad to recieve an answer, you're expected to mark an answer as factually correct so people can't reply to just parts of this

Hi Tom, thank you for your answer!
I understand! I think for now it would be most important for me to upload my website in github. From there I can go searching on my own again.
I did an export in wordpress, it said the export contains everything, including the media. But the file was to small in my opinion. Can I transfer the website via this export?

A WXR file from the WordPress exporter is not your site, it's just the content. Your code could go on GitHub but you can't run a WordPress site on GitHub, and GitHub provides no database to store that content. The only thing you can put on GitHub are files which means code usually. If you want to take the database from your computer and synchronise it to a Raspberry Pi then you will need a different separate solution that is independent of all the other parts and would be a big task all on its own. In the meantime you haven't edited your Q to narrow it down to a single specific question

hint: you can open multiple questions, you don't have to bundle them all together, and you're more likely to get longer more useful answers. This isn't a group/discussion forum so don't treat questions like the start of a conversation/message thread, and try to ground things in fact rather than opinion. You can link to other questions for context but make sure each question stands on its own and can be understood clearly
